# Use on-board graphics card instead of (broken) ATI Mobility Radeon?

Tags: ati, graphics, radeon

I've been given an old laptop that I am trying to get revived using the latest Xubuntu 14.04.

Now here's the problem, the laptop's GPU is pretty much destroyed and I usually get some ugly random horizontal lines all over the screen (that's why this laptop was taken out of use in the first place).

I am thinking, there could be a way around this, by using the on-board graphics card (it should have one, right?) instead of the ATI mobility radeon that it came with and seems to be destroyed. So, what I need is to *only* use the on-board graphics card!

I've googled around for this, but most said to do the "switch" in BIOS, no option there though. Any ideas?

Comment: what is your on board card?